# How to remove Excel sheet rows columns using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to export div data which using Jquery.it is working fine as expected But two rows and columns not required how to remove?

Image Applicant ID and Middle Name not required. how to remove?

[image]

JS:

```
let csv = $('.sample').map((i, sample) => {
    return $(sample).find('span > .labelValue').map((_, field) => field.innerText).get().join(',');
}).get();
csv.unshift('Applicant ID,First Name,Middle Name,Last Name'); // add headers
createCsvFile(csv);

function createCsvFile(csvArray) {
  let file = new Blob([csvArray.join('\r\n')], {
    type: "application/csv"
  });

  let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  let a = $("<a />", {
    href: url,
    download: "filename.csv"
  }).appendTo("body").get(0).click();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="losSection" id="secReviewerDemographics"><div class="losSectionHeader"><div class="losSectionSel losSectionTitle misign" data-originaltitle="Demographics">Demographics</div></div><div id="cpC_kf_secview_50" class="losSectionView"><div>


   <div id="ExportDetails" class="sample">
      <div class="tabularView">
         <input type="hidden" name="kaf_78" id="kaf_78" aria-label="kaf_78" value="01" class="._shCE"> 
         <div id="cpC_ctl73" class="tabularTbl flex-row start-xs">
         <div class="pad1x flex-row leftLblMode">
               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">
                  <div style="">
                     <label for="kaf_69" id="kaf_69" class="input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label">Applicant ID
                     </label>
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">
                  <div class="labelValueField">
                     <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_69" id="kaf_69">
                        <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_69" id="kaf_69" aria-label="Applicant ID">1</span>
                     </span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>

           <div class="pad1x flex-row leftLblMode">
               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">
                  <div style="">
                     <label for="kaf_70" id="klb_70" class="input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label">First Name
                     </label>
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">
                  <div class="labelValueField">
                     <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_70" id="kaf_70">
                        <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_70" id="kaf70" aria-label="Applicant First Name">NAMA</span>
                     </span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pad1x flex-row leftLblMode">
               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">
                  <div style="">
                     <label for="kaf_71" id="klb_71" class="input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label">Middle Name</label>
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">
                  <div class="labelValueField">
                     <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_71" id="kaf_71">
                        <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_71" id="kaf71" aria-label="Applicant Middle Name">VEENESH</span>
                     </span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pad1x flex-row leftLblMode">
               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">
                  <div style="">
                     <label for="kaf_72" id="klb_72" class="input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label input-control-label">Last Name
                     </label>
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">
                  <div class="labelValueField">
                     <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_72" id="kaf_72">
                        <span class="labelValue" name="kaf_72" id="kaf72" aria-label="Applicant Last Name">KUMAR</span>
                     </span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         </div>
   </div>
   </div></div>

    <button id="ExportToExcel" onclick="exportF(this)">Export To Excel</button>
```

[Demo Code](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/1tsak3cb/5/)

Comment: `$(sample).find('span > .labelValue').not( ":even" )` will solve this question, but if you want to go generic then you need do more code

Comment: @DickensAS Sometimes span value order is different. so this code won't work. Example FirstName,MiddleName,ApplicantID,LastName

Comment: yes, as I told, if you wanted to go generic, you need to do more code, the basic idea is to use DOM traversal filters and jQuery DOM code to find the position of the label and selective filtering using jquery `eq` or other css filter methods, do you want me to write a full code :)

Comment: yes @DickensAS very helpful for me

Comment: use this https://jsfiddle.net/dickensas/q56u9ow7/5/ , please do next code yourself :) :) this code can be further optimized with more structured approach, I just quickly fiddled

Comment: Thanks @DickensAS working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210368/discussion-between-dickens-a-s-and-ivin-raj).